# Docker throwing FATA[0000] Error response from daemon

Tags: docker, centos6

I have installed docker on centos 6.6 after starting docker as a service and pulling centos image

```
[root@ 17:43 ~]$docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG     IMAGE ID      CREATED      VIRTUAL SIZE
centos        6       f6808a3e4d9e  13 days ago  215.7 MB
centos        latest  88f9454e60dd  13 days ago  223.9 MB code here
```

and then I tried to start a container

```
docker run centos:6 echo "ff"
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 7a65630de2390c17d254b8c229c87f42ba81aa5b90f48b553e758ed7b0610f57: write /cgroup/cpu/docker/7a65630de2390c17d254b8c229c87f42ba81aa5b90f48b553e758ed7b0610f57/cgroup.procs: invalid argument
```

any idea why I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

This is a configuration issue with the kernel you are using.
Have a look at this bug comment, it should help you get it resolved:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6944#issuecomment-55910397

Comment: I had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 I did apt-get upgrade and then it worked.

Answer (score -2):

You must have a terminal associated   so `run -it`

Comment: still exact same error [root@ 22:09 ~]$docker run -it centos echo "hello"
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container c5d8c53e897a186233ac6000a65170709be0b6a4c9f624ff3ca4e830298ebf78: write /cgroup/freezer/docker/c5d8c53e897a186233ac6000a65170709be0b6a4c9f624ff3ca4e830298ebf78/cgroup.procs: invalid argument